# How to design a REST API for resources that depend on each other?

Tags: rest, api-design

I'm having troubles with designing a rest api for the following scenarios:

---

1. When a new user registers he/she also creates a new group.
2. New users can also join an existing group using a unique group code.
3. Existing users can create new groups.
4. Existing users can join existing groups.

---

I was thinking of doing it as below:

---

1. POST https://api.myapp.com/users (creates new user and new group, adds user to the group)
2. PATCH [https://api.myapp.com/groups/{id}](https://api.myapp.com/groups/%7Bid%7D) (creates new user, adds user to existing group)
   I don't like it that I create a new user via /groups endpoint.
3. POST [https://api.myapp.com/groups/{id}](https://api.myapp.com/groups/%7Bid%7D) (creates new group, adds user to the group)
4. PATCH [https://api.myapp.com/groups/{id}](https://api.myapp.com/groups/%7Bid%7D) (adds user to existing group)

---

I don't know how and if I should express in the api that users and groups depend on each other.
Something like:

---

/users/{id}/groups
/groups/{id}/users

---

If this is better approach then what should come first groups or users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groups should come first in URLs when you are adding a user to a group.

Group Resource:

```
{
    "id": "group1",
    "name": "Developers",
    "users": [
        {
          "id": "user1",
          "name": "John1"
        },
        {
          "id": "user2",
          "name": "John2"
        }
    ] 
}
```

User Resource:

```
{
    "id": "user1",
    "groups": "John1",
    "users": [
        {
          "id": "group1",
          "name": "Developers"
        },
        {
          "id": "group2",
          "name": "Testers"
        }
    ] 
}
```

1. Create a new group: POST https://api.myapp.com/groups

   ```
    Request URL: https://api.myapp.com/groups

    Request Body:
    {
        "name": "Developers",
    }

    Response Body:
    {
        "id": "group1",
        "name": "Developers"
    }

    HTTP Status Code: 201
   ```
2. Create a new user and add him to existing group: POST [https://api.myapp.com/groups/{groupId}/users](https://api.myapp.com/groups/%7BgroupId%7D/users)

   ```
    Request URL: https://api.myapp.com/groups/{group1}/users

    Request Body:       
    {
        "name": "John3"
    }

    Response Body:
    {
        "id": "user3",
        "name": "John3",
        "groups": [
            {
              "id": "group1",
              "name": "Developers"
            }
        ] 
    }

    HTTP Status Code: 201
   ```
3. Create a new user & group: POST https://api.myapp.com/users

   ```
    Request URL: https://api.myapp.com/users        

    Request Body:
    {
        "name": "John4",
        "groups": [
            {
              "name": "Testers"
            }
        ]
    }

    Response Body:
    {
        "id": "user4",
        "name": "John4",
        "groups": [
            {
              "id": "group2",
              "name": "Testers"
            }
        ] 
    }
   ```
4. Add an existing user to an existing group: POST [https://api.myapp.com/groups/{groupId}/users/{userId}](https://api.myapp.com/groups/%7BgroupId%7D/users/%7BuserId%7D)

   ```
    Request URL: https://api.myapp.com/groups/{group2}/users/{user1}
    Request Body: No Body
    Response Body: No Body
    HTTP Status Code: 200
   ```
5. Get a group: GET [https://api.myapp.com/groups/{groupId}](https://api.myapp.com/groups/%7BgroupId%7D)

   ```
    Request URL: https://api.myapp.com/groups/{group1}
    Response Body:
    {
        "id": "group1",
        "name": "Developers",
        "users": [
            {
              "id": "user1",
              "name": "John1"
            },
            {
              "id": "user2",
              "name": "John2"
            },
            {
              "id": "user3",
              "name": "John3"
            }
        ]
    }
   ```
6. Get a user: GET [https://api.myapp.com/users/{userId}](https://api.myapp.com/users/%7BuserId%7D)

   ```
    Request URL: https://api.myapp.com/users/{user1}

    Response Body:
    {
        "id": "user1",
        "name": "John1",
        "groups": [
            {
              "id": "group1",
              "name": "Developers"
            },
            {
              "id": "group2",
              "name": "Testers"
            }
        ] 
    }
   ```